# Blender 2.5 render will not export sound

Tags: 11.10, sound, blender

I have tried several formats, but my blender animation render will not have sound. In blender, it plays fine when I press the play button, but there is no sound in the render. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

In Response to devius:
According to the terminal, ffmpeg was not installed. I installed it. Now should it work? It takes a long time to render and I don't want to start it unless I know it's going to work.
Update: After installing ffmpeg and restarting, there was still no sound on render. I took the exported file without audio and combined it with the audio track in OpenShot. Good workaround, problem still not fixed. I am marking Explorer' s answer as the answer, even though for me it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can someone please help me answer this? I need this project rendered overnight so I can hand it in on monday.

Comment: This is tagged as `banshee`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. I have tried opening it using banshee, VLC, and Movie Player, all with no avail.

Comment: What audio output format are you using? AFAIK Blender uses FFMPEG to export video/audio so if ffmpeg can handle the format it should work. You may also try the command "ffmpeg -i [yourfile]" on a terminal to see if there's actually an audio track in there or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have `ffmpeg` as an output option in Blender.

In terminal, check whether it's installed or not:

```
~$ ffmpeg
The program 'ffmpeg' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

When you installed it, check if it's included in the format list in blender:

[image]

If not, you need to [download](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/) and reinstall blender. For some reason you have a version that was compiled without `ffmpeg` support. You could try one of the new 2.49 RC builds.

Comment: Thanks, I installed ffmpeg. I hope this fixes the problem, will render soon!

Comment: reinstalling pkg maintainers ffmpeg fixes problem... I also had a similar problem but had tried to use "non Vanilla ffmpeg"
was trying a ffmpeg i made from 4.3 but video rendered and no audio and everyone kept saying make sure audio is selected... lol

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the reason was that the audio codec was not enabled.

In the Render tab, choose the MPEG format and you will see a section called Encoding. There you can choose the video codec and the audio codec. For instance, try MPEG-4 and MP3 and you will hopefully get the audio in the output file.